# Misaligned Multivariate Time Series (weather and soil moisture) in soil moisture forecasting

Tags: time-series, forecasting

I'm working on soil moisture forecasting using multivariate time series (MTS). More precisely, each time sample comes with multiple measurements regarding: the soil (e.g. soil temperature, and soil moisture at different depths) and the weather data (e.g. temperature, rain, wind, etc.). The current weather data does not provide all the information to forecast the soil moisture that depends on future weather (e.g. rain events, temperature....). In a real situation I would have also the weather forecast, but this would cause a kind of misalignment in my MTS.

In other words I have:

- **historical data** in the range [-T_past, 0] for soil variables v1(t), v2(t), ...vn(t) and weather variables w1(t),w2(t), ..., wm(t)
- **forecast data** in the range [0, T_future] for weather variables w1(t),w2(t), ..., wm(t)

I would like to use all these available data (soil and weather historical values + weather forecast values) to predict soil moisture in range [0, T_future].

I'm currently working with standard LSTM, GRU or most recent crossformer but these approaches does not manage this situation. Is there any other approach able to manage such a case of misalignment MTS?